# MySQL query not working with php, but query runs on phpmyadmin's sql

Tags: php, mysql

So, Here is the HTML form I am using

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="2px">
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Day</td>
<td>Height</td>
<td>Weight</td>
<td>Biceps(Open)</td>
<td>Biceps(Curled)</td>
<td>Photo</td>
<td>Action</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="date" name = "date"></td>
<td><select name="day">
<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) { ?>
    <option>
    <?php echo $x;
} ?></option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><select name="height">
    <?php for ($x = 170; $x <= 180; $x++) { ?>
    <option>
    <?php echo $x;
} ?></option>
    </select> Centimeters &nbsp;
</td>
<td><select name="weight">
    <?php for ($x = 60; $x <= 80; $x++) { ?>
    <option>
    <?php echo $x;
} ?></option>
    </select> Kilograms &nbsp;
</td>
<td><select name="biceps_o">
    <?php for ($x = 10; $x <= 15; $x++) { ?>
    <option>
    <?php echo $x;
} ?></option>
    </select> Inches &nbsp;
</td>
<td><select name="biceps_c">
    <?php for ($x = 10; $x <= 15; $x++) { ?>
    <option>
    <?php echo $x;
} ?></option>
    </select> Inches &nbsp;
</td>
    Select image to upload:
<td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and here is the upload.php file

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $biceps_o = $_POST['biceps_o'];
    $biceps_c = $_POST['biceps_c'];

    echo $sql_query = "INSERT INTO gym (date, day, height, weight, biceps_o, biceps_c, image) VALUES('$date', '$day', '$height', '$weight', '$biceps_o', '$biceps_c', '$target_file')";
    if($sql_result = mysql_query($sql_query))
    echo "Data Successfully Added!";
    else
    echo "Data Entry Failed!";
?>
```

but when i run the code and upload my data it gives the following

> File is an image - image/jpeg.The file
>   aid62387-728px-Cross-Your-Eyes-Step-2.jpg has been uploaded.INSERT
>   INTO gym (date, day, height, weight, biceps_o, biceps_c, image)
>   VALUES('2016-08-15', '1', '170', '60', '10', '10',
>   'images/aid62387-728px-Cross-Your-Eyes-Step-2.jpg')Data Entry Failed!

well, the image is uploaded perfectly but the query does not quite run properly.
BUT the same query

> INSERT INTO gym (date, day, height, weight, biceps_o, biceps_c, image)
>   VALUES('2016-08-15', '1', '170', '60', '10', '10',
>   'images/aid62387-728px-Cross-Your-Eyes-Step-2.jpg')

works perfectly fine when I run it in phpmyadmin's sql. what might be the problem?

Comment: use mysql_error to find out what is happen

Comment: **Stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Statements, to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: where is your mysql connection?

Comment: Also, I'm not too familiar with PHP, but it sems to me that you're not escaping your inputs at all, making it very susceptible to sql injections!

Comment: <?php 
//echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];die;
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost' or $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '127.0.0.1') 
{
 $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
 $mysql_user = "root";
 $mysql_password = "";
 $mysql_database = "for_testing";
}


$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("Could not connect database");
?>

my mysql connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think have not include ur database connection, like php

Answer (score -1):

You are using a reserved mysql keyword (date). Quote the query as follow:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO gym (`date`, `day`, `height`, `weight`, `biceps_o`, `biceps_c`, `image`) VALUES('$date', '$day', '$height', '$weight', '$biceps_o', '$biceps_c', '$target_file')";
```

And also add some escapes arround the values (like mysql_real_escape_string) or start using PDO.